# MVC2 Data Annotation Buddy Classes Doesn't seem to work when Classes and EOM Model is in separate Project

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-2, project, data-annotations

I am new to MVC2 and having a little problem with implementing validation via buddy classes.
I am using Repository pattern with dependency injection.
My Entity Object Model is in Data Layer Project and Buddy Classes are in Business Layer project and MVC 2 Project as a separate Presentation Layer Project.

Can any one help me out with implementing Buddy Classes in this Architecture?

Comment: Well after playing around abit.. i figured out that i need to use my Buddy class while creating views and it will then validate. Now here is another kicker?
Do i need a mapper class to map buddy class properties with model entity class.if yes then why is it not req. when i keep buddy classes and model in same project?

Answer (score 0):

Partial classes work only within the same assembly. So you have two possibilities: define validation rules in the same assembly as your model classes or don't use DataAnnotations. As an alternative you may take a look at [FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) allowing you to define validation rules in a separate assembly and which has a great integration with ASP.NET MVC as well.

As far as the views in your MVC project are concerned they should never work with your model classes. You should define view model classes which are specifically tailored to the needs of each view. The controller will then perform the mapping between the models and the view models. [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) could be used to ease this task. So basically all user input like required fields and datetime formats should be validated at the view model and business rules at the service layer.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. So in my case data annotations is out of the question.Cool.But when i use my Buddy Classs to create a strongly typed view then validations work fine. Should i go with it ? Or would you recommend FluentValidation.Can I send you my project so that you can review it and give me some advise on it as well.?Thanks again.